# limit of an infinite sum $y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^2}{n^3+n+k}$. Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n$

I see that the terms in $y_n$ are lie between $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}$.
I am unable to form the telescoping series to get the limit.

P.S. Sorry if this is too basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

You may squeeze $y_n$ as follows:

- For $k=1, \ldots , n$ you have 
  $$\frac{n^2}{n^3+2n} \leq \frac{n^2}{n^3+n+k} \leq \frac{n^2}{n^3+n}$$
  It follows
  $$n\cdot \frac{n^2}{n^3+2n} \leq y_n \leq n \cdot \frac{n^2}{n^3+n}$$

Now, take the limits on both sides.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it too !

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Comment: Cauchy's first theorem fir limits can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

If you know harmonic numbers,
$$\displaystyle y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^2}{n^3+n+k}=n^2 \left(H_{n^3+2 n}-H_{n^3+n}\right)$$ Now, using, for large $p$
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ and continuing with long division or better with Taylor series for large $n$, you should get
$$y_n=1-\frac{3}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ For example
$$y_{10}=\frac{6646021071305823047954845}{6748980404790313121758326}\approx 0.9847$$ while the above approximation would give $\frac{197}{200}=0.9850$.